# Prove that if $ab = 1$ for $a, b \in A$, then $a = b^{-1}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $A$ be a unital finite-dimensional algebra over a field $\mathbb{K}$ and $a,b \in A$. I have a question to the following statement:

> If $ab = 1$, then $a = b^{-1}$.

Originally, I thought this follows from definition, but I guess we have to show uniqueness? I asked my lecturer for some advice and he told me to think about how to represent $A$ in matrices. I am lost. Any pointers on how to approach this, or perhaps how to break this down so I can accumulate an understanding of how this works? Thanks heaps.

Comment: If this is a poor question, please let me know, I'll remove it immediately. I feel my understanding is lacking and I may need to revisit fundamentals.

Comment: Can you write out the definition you have of the expression $b^{-1}$ in full?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you're probing @Billy, mind you an inverse of $a$ is such a $b$ where $ab = 1 = ba$.

Comment: Where 1 can be any identity of any group by the way. So rather I should use $e$

Comment: Right - your definition says that an inverse of $b$ is some $a$ (swapping the ordering to make this fit your question!) such that $ab = 1$ **and** $ba = 1$. You know that $ab = 1$, and now you need to prove that $ba = 1$.

Comment: This isn't group theory, by the way: you don't know that a and b are invertible until you've proved it, so you don't know that they actually sit inside a multiplicative group!

Comment: @FlorianSuess In an algebra is better to use $0,1$ instead of $e$... if you use $e$, do you mean the identity for addition or multiplication?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint** For each $a \in A$ define $T_a: A \to A$ via
$$T_a(x)=ax$$

Then $T_a$ is a linear transformation and $T_aT_b=Id$.

Deduce from here that if $[T_a], [T_b]$ are the corresponding matrices with respect to some fixed basis then
$$[T_a][T_b]=I_n$$
and hence 
$$[T_b][T_a]=I_n$$

Use this to show that $ba=1$.

Comment: So I should assume the existence of a finite basis $B =${$b_1,b_2, ...$}. Then define $[T_a] = [T_a(b_1)|T_a(b_2)|...]$ right? Similarly with $[T_b]$. Then $[T_a][T_b]=I_n=[T_b]^{-1}[T_a]^{-1} = ([T_b][T_a])^{-1} = I_n$ and then show equivalence to  $([T_b][T_a]) = I_n^{-1} = I_n$.

Comment: Mind you, I'm assuming the basis is finite (I should have made that a little clearer).

Comment: @FlorianSuess yes, that is the idea. the key here is that for square matrices you know that $AB=I_n \Rightarrow BA=I_n$... also note that the claim is not true in infinite dimensional algebras.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the $\mathbb{K}$-linear map $\lambda_b\colon A\to A$, $\lambda_b(x)=bx$. Similarly you have $\lambda_a$ and, by assumption,
$$
\lambda_a\circ\lambda_b=\iota
$$
where $\iota$ is the identity on $A$. Therefore $\lambda_b$ is injective. Since $A$ is finite dimensional, $\lambda_b$ is also surjective. Therefore $\lambda_b$ has an inverse $\mathbb{K}$-linear map $f$ and we need to prove $f=\lambda_a$.

This is easy:
$$
\lambda_a=\lambda_a\circ\iota=\lambda_a\circ(\lambda_b\circ f)=
(\lambda_a\circ\lambda_b)\circ f=\iota\circ f=f
$$

No matrices needed.